# PrP Continuous vs. PrP | Nuance?

Tags: present-tense, nuance, perfect-aspect, continuous-aspect

I have a question regarding the usage of the Present Perfect and the Present Perfect Continuous.

So first, here's the context: I was playing an online game with a couple friends and in this game you have to go into dungeons which have treasure chests at their end and these chests normally contain valuable items (some do not) and normally you do those dungeons just to make money.
Anyway, we made our way through a dungeon right to the end of it and then one of my buddies opened the chest and we looted the items. Then I asked him if there was anything valuable you could get out of the chest in that specific dungeon as I hadn't been sure about it. We were still in the dungeon.
He told me there actually was something of high value obtainable and I replied with either (I've forgotten what EXACTLY I said but I'll try to recall as best as possible):

- **Oh I didn't know, I've always been playing this dungeon only for fun.** (but now I might consider playing it for the valuable items)

or

- **Oh I didn't know, so far I've been playing this dungeon only for fun.** (but now I might consider playing it for the valuable items)

Now my question is that if I had used the "simple" Present Perfect, would the meaning drastically change?
Could I have said it like this:

- **Oh I didn't know, I've always played this dungeon only for fun.** (but now I might consider playing it for the valuable items)

or

- **Oh I didn't know, so far I've played this dungeon only for fun.** (but now I might consider playing it for the valuable items)

To me it feels like both are right, there's only a slight nuance namely that in the version with the PrP Contionuous I convey that I played the dungeon more frequently or habitually than in the simple PrP version but maybe I'm completely wrong, I don't know.

So, what do feel or think when hearing something like that and which version would you choose?

I'm looking forward to reading your answers. :)

Comment: None of them are normal English and there will be complaints that your question isn't precise enough. A native speaker might say "I've only been playing this dungeon for fun".

Comment: "always been playing" doesn't really work, because "always" here doesn't match with the suggestion that the action will continue. As TheMathemagician says, "I've only been playing" is fine, as is "I've always played". Note that the present perfect doesn't inherently mean that you won't continue to, nor that you won't change, your motivation.

Comment: @nxx Thank you for your answer, so "always been doing" would mean that I'll definitely continue to play only for fun, excluding that I'm planning on going in there for rare items in the future? Like when you say: "I've always been doing it like this (and I'm not gonna do it any different now!)". And "I've always played[...]for fun" doesn't exclude the possibility of me changing my motivation (from playing only for fun to playing for rare items) as it doesn't imply that I'm going to continue playing only for fun but only that I have up to now played for fun. Did I get that right?

Comment: Hmm I meant that the past continuous tense and "always" don't go together (it wouldn't always be wrong, but it is not the clearest or most natural choice). So instead of "I have always been playing" you would say "I have been playing this dungeon only for fun for the last 10 years" or "I've always played it like this" or "I've only been playing it this way". Any of these can mean that you will continue to ("and I'm not going to change that now") or that you will change ("but now I will play it differently"). I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, **present perfect** continuous.

Comment: @nxx Yes it does make sense, thank you for your answer. It's clear to me now.

Answer (score 1):

There are some interesting subtleties here. Was this the first time you had ever entered this particular dungeon, or had you been there before in previous game sessions? If this was your first visit, the continuous aspect might be more appropriate: at every point in time since you began the activity, you have been playing the dungeon for fun (as opposed to sleeping, eating, or doing other things outside the game world.) If you've been to this dungeon multiple times on discrete occasions, then there is no continuous activity, and so the ordinary present perfect (or even the pluperfect) might be more appropriate.

However, a good case could be made that either of the forms could be used in either circumstance, as it ultimately boils down to the semantics of the word *play* and how it can be used (e.g., you can say "I play golf" even if you're not actively playing golf at the moment that you utter the words). In practical terms, the choice probably only matters if you believe it's important to convey that you either have or haven't been in the dungeon previously.

Comment: Thank you for your answer phenry. :) I had been to the dungeon multiple times before I said what I said. Imagine I'm still in that dungeon. When I use the normal present perfect version now I convey that I have been in there before at least once or multiple times on several occasions and when I use the continuous form I only talk about this single process of playing the dungeon, conveying that I have been playing it only for fun this time (since I began that specific dungeon) and giving no implication of there being other occasions before where I have played for fun. What do you think?